# How to integrate Unity code in Xcode code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Has anybody worked on Unity?? Please tell if anybody tried to integrate unity code with Xcode code.

Comment: What do you really wish to do exactly? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't integrate the code exactly. You can use plugins in Unity to communicate between the unity project and the xcode objective c code.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/142849/uikit.html

http://prime31.com/unity/

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/56017-expand-Unity-apps-with-UIKit